# StringGrid. Проверка на корректность ввода

Tags: c++builder

Мне надо, чтобы после ввода числа в ячейку, программа проверяла число на заданный формат.
Например, вводим число 5, а получаем 5,00.
Проверку на корректность во время ввода я написал (проверяет, чтобы не было букв, и запятая была).

Comment: В чем вопрос ? Корректна ли Ваша проверка ? 

Я обычно беру за основу strtol() для целых и strtod() для действительных чисел, но это сильно зависит от задачи (правил для корректного формата "ячейки").

Comment: Мне надо название события, при выходе из ячейки. Чтобы при выходе из ячейки была проверка.

Comment: Почему то событие onExit не отрабатывается, если я даже выхожу из этой формы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы могли бы осуществить проверку интересующих Вас ячеек в цикле после выхода из Grid'a (OnExit) функцией TryStrToFloat(...). Тут и **собственная** проверка не нужна.
Еще рекомендуют вставлять проверки в **OnSetEditText**.